# What is causing this php script designed to backup large mysql tables to run out of memory?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote this script which is designed to backup MySQL tables selectively from PHP while reliably keeping the data types intact.

The problem is that recently, it has started to give me a memory exhaustion error, even though I am clearing the data on each cycle through the loop.

My code is as follows (i placed a comment showing the line numbers from the error as this is a much larger script - this is the entire backup portion. the `$file` param is actually a `path` but i have been too lazy to rename it):

```
public static function backup($tables, $file)
{
    $return       = ''; // LINE 1221
    $file_written = false;

    //get all of the tables
    if ($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array(); // LINE 1226
        $result = mysqli_query(self::$cn, 'SHOW TABLES');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    } else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
    }

    // Initialize File
    $filename = $file . 'db-backup-' . time() . '-' . (md5(implode(',', $tables))) . '.sql';
    echo $filename; die(); // placed this here so I could see
                           // if it was running out of memory above
                           // and this echos out fine, so the problem
                           // is somewhere below.
    $handle   = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fclose($handle);
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');

    //cycle through
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        if ($table <> "") {
            $result = mysqli_query(self::$cn, 'SELECT * FROM `' . $table . '`');
            if ($result) {
                $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query(self::$cn, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `' . $table . '`'));
                if ($row2) {
                    $file_written = true;
                    $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $table . '`;';
                    $return .= "\n\n" . $row2[1] . ";\n\n";

                    $field_flags = false;
                    fwrite($handle, $return);
                    $return = '';

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

                            if ($field_flags == false) {
                                for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
                                    $tmp = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $j);
                                    if (strpos($tmp->flags, 'NOT_NULL') !== false) {
                                        $field_flags[$j] = false;
                                    } else {
                                        $field_flags[$j] = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // var_dump($field_flags); die();
                            $return .= 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` VALUES(';
                            for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
                                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                                $row[$j] = preg_replace("/\n/", "\\n", $row[$j]);
                                if (isset($row[$j])) {
                                    if ($row[$j] <> '') {
                                        $return .= '"' . $row[$j] . '"';
                                    } else {
                                        if ($field_flags[$j]) {
                                            $return .= "NULL";
                                        } else {
                                            $return .= '""';
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if ($field_flags[$j]) {
                                        $return .= "NULL";
                                    } else {
                                        $return .= '""';
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($j < ($num_fields - 1)) {
                                    $return .= ',';
                                }
                            }
                            $return .= ");\n";
                            fwrite($handle, $return);
                            $return = '';
                        }
                    }
                    $return .= "\n\n\n";
                    fwrite($handle, $return);
                    $return = '';
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);

    //save file
    if ($file_written) {
        return $filename;
    } else {
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            unlink($filename);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I wrote this about 7 years ago, and haven't had the time to rewrite this in PDO or fully assess whether this conversion would be of any benefit.

The message I am getting is as follows (line 31 is just calling the method):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in d:\server\htdocs\backup.php on line 1221, referer: http://example.com/index.html
PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://example.com/index.html
PHP   1. {main}() d:\server\htdocs\backup.php:0, referer: http://example.com/index.html
PHP   2. mysqli_db::backup() d:\server\htdocs\backup.php:31, referer: http://example.com/index.html
PHP   3. mysqli_fetch_field_direct() d:\server\htdocs\backup.php:1221, referer: http://example.com/index.html
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in d:\server\htdocs\backup.php on line 1226, referer: http://example.com/index.html
```

Comment: Did your data size grow over time? If yes, then the data written through `fwrite` occupies memory too. The larger the data the more memory it will consume.

Comment: @Samir - it has grown, but not that much.  This code easily wrote out 500MB-1GB files ... and this is now barfing on only 17MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's the resultset, [due to mysqlnd driver](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd) (this is my article about PDO, but it's applicable for mysqli as well).

To solve, you have to add [`MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to mysqli_query(),

```
$result = mysqli_query(self::$cn, 'SELECT * FROM `' . $table . '`', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

Also, move your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query above SELECT, as you cannot run other queries while an unbuffered query is active.

Comment: Made some progress it seems, but now it's stuck on this line `$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query(self::$cn, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE \`' . $table . '\`'));` with this message *PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result* .  Making the result read only was a great idea (i didn't know about that param until you pointed it out)

Comment: yes, you cannot run other queries while an unbuffered query is active. move your show create table query above select *. BTW, if ($result) { condition is useless

Comment: I have it underneath as it is conditional on if there are any rows to export.  Not sure how to position that logic cleanly outside the condition. `$result` returns a boolean false if not set to an object (as far as I know).

Comment: It makes no sense for two reasons. First, **this condition has nothing to do with the number of rows to export**. Second, it makes no sense to throw away a table from a backup only because it contain no rows. So in effect right now your code effectively backups ALL tables including empty ones (as it should) while condition being just useless

Comment: Just to give a bit of context on the "backup".  It is selective - if there are results.  The backup is then restored overtop of tables on a different machine.  These tables contain modified records as well as new records, some tables may not have results here where they do on the db they are "restored" to.  It's kind of a hackish way to transition data and keep a local copy since other backup methods usually corrupt it somehow.  This has been stable until recently.  I moved the `show create` line above - will have to double back and cleanup the logic later.   It appears to be working now :)

Comment: Either way, your code right now doesn't check for the empty results at all. And it could be tricky to add such a condition.

Comment: I just noticed that.  Functionally, it looks like it operates as intended still (unless that query doesn't return back something that evaluates to false as it used to on an empty result set).   I did that as a bit of a hack to avoid reading ahead for a count using mysql_num_rows.  Checking if that has changed now. Doc seems the same in this regard `Returns FALSE on failure` -- now the question is :  is an empty result set still reported back as a failure - or...  does it store an object with 0 loops

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use  mysql_num_rows with unbuffered query. you will have to add some hand-made condition to see whether you entered the loop at least once.